# "undefined reference to" error caused by number representation

Tags: c, numbers, precision

When I try compiling my C file, part of the code shown below gives me an error. The compiler I am using is arm-none-eabi.

```
int len = 9;
uint8_t i;

for(i=0; i<len; i++){
  float min = ((3.3f*i)/len);  //this is line 32 in my code
  float max = ((3.3f+(3.3f*i))/len); //this is line 33 in my code
}
```

The error produced is:

```
template.o: In function `main':
template.c:32: undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2f'
template.c:32: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fmul'
template.c:32: undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2f'
template.c:32: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fdiv'
template.c:33: undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2f'
template.c:33: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fmul'
template.c:33: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fadd'
template.c:33: undefined reference to `__aeabi_i2f'
template.c:33: undefined reference to `__aeabi_fdiv'
```

This obviously has to do with the number representations. Since I am still a beginner in C programming, I can not figure out how to solve this problem, even after doing some research. My attempt was to make 3.3 a float by adding an 'f' to it which did not fix anything. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use a Makefile or link manually? And how exactly?

Comment: `min` and `max` are library defined macros in some C implementations.

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I use a Makefile to compile and link. This is how the linking part looks:
`template.elf: template.o startup.o
 arm-none-eabi-ld -T stm32f051.ld -o template.elf template.o startup.o` 
startup is the system initializations file. stm32f051 is my microprocessor that I am running the code on

Comment: These missing definitions are are type conversion functions. Have you included the relevant header file/library? Per the first hit in Google, the necessary library is fplib (http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0097a/armcc_cjaidcjb.htm)

Comment: @levengli Thanks, that seems like the fix. How do I add this library though? I tried `#include <fplib.h>`, but this gives an error.

Comment: @WeatherVane Running the code with other variable names produces the same error

Comment: remove that `#include <fblib.h>` statement  then in the makefile, at the end of the link command `ld`, append `-lfplib`  Note that is a lowercase elll as in j, k l, m

Comment: Note: the first iteration of the loop will result in:  0/len and 3.3f/len  Are you sure that is what you want to do?  Also, the loop keeps throwing away the calculated values, except for the last iteration through the loop  which will result in: 3.3f*(len-1)/len  and 3.3f  Is that really what you want to do?

Comment: Per the previous link, "plib is available as part of the standard distribution of the RealView Development Suite of C libraries". Do you have these?